# Identification char in Label

Tags: c#, wpf, label

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. WPF App.
I have to send 3 parameters in TCP Listener ( between java android client and c# server)
To send one long string it work. so I sending like this :
32.234, 23,54321, 54.5432
As you can see there are 3 numbers. I want to save any number in variable.
How can i do it ? 
I have all the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string and convert to double:

```
string stringValue = "32.234, 23,54321, 54.5432";
double[] values = stringValue.Split(new [] {", "}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                        .Select(s => Convert.ToDouble(s)).ToArray();
```

Assuming all values are separated by **`", "`** and value will always be convertible to double value.

Comment: I did it, it wrong dude.
I write :  
values = lbl_Azimuth.Content.ToString().Split(new[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
                                .Select(s => Convert.ToDouble(s)).ToArray();

it type an error : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Comment: Never mind, I found my problem in my code. Thanks it work like a magic :)